# tkinter cannot find the tk attribute

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

from another answer about tkinter issues I have tried the following code:

```
import tkinter

tkinter._test()
```

to which i get the error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mickh\Dropbox\python code\helloWorld\GUI.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "C:\Users\mickh\Dropbox\python code\helloWorld\tkinter.py", line 13, in <module>
    root = tkinter.tk()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tk' (most likely due to a circular import).
```

My python version is 3.9.7 on windows 11

Also, the error msg says that the module is partially initialized. What does this mean?

I have looked at other answers to this question by I don't understand them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a file named `tkinter.py` in your project folder. When you do `import tkinter` in your code, python will import that file rather than the installed tkinter module.

The solution is to rename `tkinter.py` to something else.

Comment: thanks, I did have a file called that. I changed the name but it didnt work, so I created a new directory and a new file and re-ran the code. Still get the same result :(

Comment: @MickHawkes: the problem is literally that python is trying to import your own file named tkinter.py (or maybe tkinter.pyc).

Comment: I closed everything down, rebooted and just reloaded the new directory and file and it still gives the error!

Comment: I rechecked my directories and no files called tkinter exists. I have reloaded the VSCode window and restarted it several times with only the GUI directory open which contains only the test.py file, which is the one Im running

Comment: Soooo I got it to finally work. Also, I found that Root = tk() doesnt work, Tk() works. Im confused, I thought Tk was only for python2?

Comment: @MickHawkes: no, the root window class has always been `Tk`. The name of the module was `Tkinter` in python 2, and changed to `tkinter` in python 3.